# Excel PowerQuery AttributeRelationship Error

Tags: mysql, excel, powerpivot, powerquery, excel-2016

I created an excel pivot chart by connecting to MySQL Database.
I am using Excel 2016, the connection was made via PowerQuery which is builtin; I then performed certain Transforms on the data in Query Editor and created a few charts.
Everything was getting auto refreshed and all was good.

Due to some issues, we had to change the MySQL Schema. Change as in; we added a few extra columns.
Since then I am getting this weird error whenever I try to refresh my DataSet.
Check this error.[AttributeRelationship Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGhzc.png)

Advanced Editor Code [first few lines]:

```
let
Source = MySQL.Database("192.168.70.104", "prm",   [ReturnSingleDatabase=true]),
prm_tbloutpatient = Source{[Schema="prm",Item="tbloutpatient"]}[Data],
```

Please guide.

--

Regards

SAurabha J

Comment: Why wouldn't you provide code?

At least first few lines are required, where a connection to the database is made.

Comment: You might want to try "Send a frown" to Excel 2016. I don't know if you'll hear anything back, but they track metrics for common issues and that's how we decide which issues to fix :)

Comment: @Eugene - There is no code written. If you are referring to the one generated in Advanced Editor, I have updated in my question.

Comment: @CarlWalsh - Already sent a frown :)

Comment: @sau6402: Seems Ok.  Try creating a new query and using these lines to open the db. If you still get the error,  try "refresh all" for preview. If problem persists, this is probably a bug in PQ. It seems that PQ doesn't refresh table list. You can also try clearing PQ cache to overcome it.